# To specify a required field group QRadioButton in QWizard

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I need to go to the next page in the wizard only if one of their radiobutton selected and remember what it was pressed.

My class QWizardPage:

```
rb1 = QRadioButton('Button 1')
rb2 = QRadioButton('Button 2')
rb3 = QRadioButton('Button 3')
group = QButtonGroup()
group.addButton(rb1)
group.addButton(rb2)
group.addButton(rb3)
registerField('regFile*', group, group.buttonClicked)
```

Error message:

```
TypeError: registerField(self, str, QWidget, property: str = None, changedSignal: PYQT_SIGNAL = 0): argument 2 has unexpected type 'QButtonGroup'
```

P.S. Python3 & PtQt5

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at [the docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwizardpage.html#registerField) for this `registerField()` method. The main problem is that it expects a `QWidget` argument, but a `QButtonGroup` is not a subclass of `QWidget`, it's a subclass of `QObject`. You also didn't supply a `property` argument, which might be necessary for widgets that are not on the list of 'known' widgets in the documentation for this method.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there must be a better way, but as a workaround, I created an extra `QRadioButton` and made it a required field through `registerField()`. But did *not* make it visible. Clicking any of the visible radio-buttons calls the `toggle()` slot of the hidden radio-button, thus allowing the wizard to proceed.

```
QRadioButton *completion_button = new QRadioButton();
registerField("completion*", completion_button);
connect(radio_button_1,SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),completion_button ,SLOT(toggle()));
connect(radio_button_2,SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),completion_button ,SLOT(toggle()));
```

The hidden widget didn't have to be a `QRadioButton`; it could have been any `QWidget` with a slot that would fulfill the page requirement. But it seemed simpler to stick with the same object-type.